# Detecting onFling gestures

Tags: android

I tried the code from the [android gesture guide](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html).

```
class GraphGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener
{
    private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "Gestures";

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent event)
    {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onDown: " + event.toString());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2,
            float velocityX, float velocityY)
    {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,
                "onFling: " + event1.toString() + event2.toString());
        return true;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if I'm missing the point here, but I never manage to get the onFling message to show in LogCat when I perform said gesture on my device. I keep getting onDown instead. Is it because onDown intercepts it every time?

Comment: The problem isn't with the onDown getting in your way since you are returning true all the time.

Comment: This is an inner-class inside a regular view. I've added the detector.onTouchEvent inside of the view's onTouchEvent, there doesn't seem to be anything else to be done. Not to mention the event are fired since I can capture onDown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it.

I had onTouchEvent in my view from a previous example :

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    this._detector.onTouchEvent(event);
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

By returning the detector's onTouchEvent result I now successfully capture all events :

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    return this._detector.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

I'm new to android though and this was just on a whim. Does anyone have a reasonable explanation as to why the first sample was blocking other events?